# Совместная разработка проекта на python на Windows и MacOS проблемы кодировки

Tags: кодировка, utf-8, windows-1251

Господа подскажите как решить проблему.

Разрабатываю приложение используя pycharm на маке кодировка дефолт utf-8.
При открытии этого же проекта на винде в пайчарм каракули. поставил кодировку utf-8 в пайчарме - изменений нет. Как быть куда копать?[image: пайчармик]